# Login to Docker using JFrog with OpenID

Tags: docker, artifactory

I just finished setting up OpenID for logging into my JFrog instance. It works from the UI, but I can't login using `docker login`.

I tried `docker login jfrog.mycompany.com`, provided by email and password that works for OpenID, but login fails with bad credentials.

I did some poking around the JFrog docs, and tried `docker login jfrog.mycompany.com/openid-connect-server-webapp/authorize` but to no avail.

Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be any examples out there showing how this is accomplished for JFrog, let alone OpenID in general. Either I'm overcomplicating this, or just doing something wrong.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As openID is SAML based, you should generate the API key from the UI and then use it. Do refer to this [KB article](https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/how-to-perform-docker-login-with-a-saml-user/) for more insight.